# Setting the CALayer bounds and position from a view controller

Tags: ios, calayer, drawrect

1. I have one set of view controller(.h, .m and .XIB)
2. I have one set of view(.h&.m)

3.The view class is responsible for drawing gauge using
-->drawRect
-->CALayer and sublayers
In this view I have initialize method, and this method only i set the bounds for my layers and sublayers

In my view controller, I have created 5 views in my xib and .h and i am assigning the same view class for all the 5 views.

Now the problem is, all 5 views differ in their position and bounds. But my drawRect view class has only one set of bounds for all views. So if I hardcode the bounds and position in initialize method with respect to one view, the remaining 4 views are getting affected. Please let me know if u know where iam going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+initialize` method is a static method, meaning it affects all instances of that class. Use the `-init` method (or a custom `-init` method) to set different bounds for your views.

At least I hope I understand your question correctly. Please post some code if this doesn't help

Comment: hi bob thanks for ur response.. But can u pls elaborate or provide some sample code regarding init or custom init..

Comment: I'm not sure what you currently use the `initialize` method for. Could you post the code for that? EDIT: and your drawRect too, please